# Android Proguard text encoding issue

Tags: android, character-encoding, proguard

**EDIT 2: Proguard does not break Strings: bad source file character encoding management do!**

(My initial question is below)

To put this in a nutshell: compiling on eclipse is fine (whatever the java source char encoding is).
But I do compile with Jenkins for release.

I had to change source encoding from ISO-8859-1 to  UTF-8 (I am on Mac, not sure this happens on Windows)

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 "$file" > "${file%.java}.utf8.java";
```

Let Javac Compiler knows about that:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

For all my java files:

```
find /path_to_mys_workspace/workspace -name \*.java -type f | \
    (while read file; do
        iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 "$file" > "${file%.java}.utf8.java";
        rm "$file";
        mv "${file%.java}.utf8.java" "$file";
    done);
```

(I also told eclipse to work in UTF-8)

```
Preferences
  -> General
     -> Workspace
       -> DefaultFile encoding : UTF-8
```

And now it works!

(Also, I ran into this problem because of some hard coded french strings in code... -1 for me.)

---

### My initial question:

Proguard is nice, but not always easy to configure...

I am using Proguard to build the release version of my set of Android apps (apps collaborating together).

I am almost there, but I am facing some string related issues:

**1 - String encoding problem**

Some foreign character (in strings within code), that are correctly displayed in debug mode, are now replaced by �, the UTF [REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), in release (i.e., after proguard processing).

Example:

```
The french 'à' is now displayed as �
```

**̶2̶ ̶-̶ ̶B̶r̶o̶k̶e̶n̶ ̶B̶r̶o̶a̶d̶c̶a̶s̶t̶ ̶a̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶ **

**EDIT: Broadcast are not broken at all: I forget/made mistakes in some proguard statements.**

̶I̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶i̶n̶e̶d̶ ̶s̶o̶m̶e̶ ̶p̶u̶b̶l̶i̶c̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶i̶c̶ ̶f̶i̶n̶a̶l̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶n̶g̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶m̶y̶

```
c̶o̶m̶.̶<̶m̶y̶_̶a̶p̶p̶_̶n̶a̶m̶e̶>̶.̶i̶n̶t̶e̶n̶t̶.̶C̶o̶n̶s̶t̶a̶n̶t̶s̶
```

̶c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶,̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶I̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶e̶d̶

```
-̶k̶e̶e̶p̶ ̶p̶u̶b̶l̶i̶c̶ ̶c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶.̶<̶m̶y̶_̶a̶p̶p̶_̶n̶a̶m̶e̶>̶.̶i̶n̶t̶e̶n̶t̶.̶*̶
```

̶i̶n̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶P̶r̶o̶g̶u̶a̶r̶d̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶ ̶f̶i̶l̶e̶.̶

̶I̶n̶ ̶r̶e̶l̶e̶a̶s̶e̶,̶ ̶*̶*̶m̶y̶ ̶b̶r̶o̶a̶d̶c̶a̶s̶t̶s̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶*̶*̶,̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶a̶b̶l̶y̶ ̶b̶e̶e̶n̶ ̶'̶b̶r̶o̶k̶e̶n̶'̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶g̶u̶a̶r̶d̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶c̶e̶s̶s̶i̶n̶g̶.̶ 
How can I fix those problems?

***Important note:***

I have one library project and many app projects using the library project.
The broadcast constants are defined in the library project and used in app projects. What is the prorper way to 'protect' those strings while **proguarding all the apps**?

Should I play with -injars in.jar -outjars out.jar -libraryjars etc..?

**Additional info:**

Release build is done in Jenkins Factory. Not sure it's usefull info, but wanted to mention it for completeness of my explanation.

---

Here is my Proguard config file used by all apps and the library project.

```
##
## my rules
##

-dontwarn org.joda.time.**,org.apache.harmony.**,com.google.vending.licensing.**,javax.security.**,java.beans.**,java.awt.**

-keep public class com.<my_package>.intent.**
{
     *;
}

#-keep public class * extends android.app.BaseActivity
-keep public class * extends com.<my_package>.shared.fragment.BaseFragment

-keepclassmembers class * extends com.<my_package>.shared.activity.BaseActivity {
   public boolean *();
   public boolean *(android.view.View);
   public void *();
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends com.<my_package>.shared.fragment.BaseFragment {
   public boolean *();
   public boolean *(android.view.View);
   public void *();
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

##
## common rules
##

-keep public class com.bugsense.*

#-repackageclasses ''
#-allowaccessmodification
#-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

##
## base proguard file content
##

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Conclusion: Proguard is amazing and working great. Thanks to Proguard team :-)

Answer (score 1):

ProGuard should not modify any strings at all. You should make sure that you are using a recent release (4.8 or 4.9 beta, at this time) inside the Android SDK (android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar). You can check which version you have with

```
java -jar android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar
```

On a related note, your configuration suggests that you are using an older Android SDK, since project-specific and project-independent configuration are now specified separately, as of SDK r20 (respectively in proguard-project.txt and in android-sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt). Simply upgrading the SDK may already help.

If the problem persists, you can file a bug report on the [ProGuard website](http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/).

Comment: Eric, I just read this in Proguard version history (4.4): "Fixed decoding of UTF-8 strings containing special characters."... Seems quite similar to my issue...

Comment: My Configuration: SDK tools: 21.1, PlatformTool: 16.0.2, ProGuard, version 4.7

Comment: Eric, problem solved. Thanks for your time. I will have a look at DexGuard to see what benifts it brings over Proguard.